# Android Resize Image and save device storage

Tags: image, resize, save

I'm doing a project. I need your help because I do not know too much about image resizing.
I want to do 240px*180px as the size of the photos taken to record. I use code like below and Thank you to everyone interested in the topic.

Thank you all!

```
public void takePhoto(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "Pic.jpg");
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
    }


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case 1:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                        .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(this, selectedImage.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

}
```